# How to make Table in PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to make table with this result (look Echo),  When I put it in the table it happens is all the results are not in one table but one result of one table.

```
foreach ($item_array as $ia_key => $ia_value) 
    {
        //$theitems = explode('|',$ia_key);
        for($x = 0; $x < count($ia_key); $x++) 
        {
            if (($ia_value>=$support))
            {
                echo "$ia_key($ia_value)";
                echo "<br>";
                $z++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried with this code. But the result is not in one table.

```
foreach ($item_array as $ia_key => $ia_value) 
    {
        //$theitems = explode('|',$ia_key);
        for($x = 0; $x < count($ia_key); $x++) 
        {
            if (($ia_value>=$support))
            {
                echo "<div class='row'>";
                    echo "<div class='col-sm-12'>";
                        echo "<h4 class='m-t-0 header-title'></h4>";
                        echo "<div class='table-responsive m-b-20'>";
                            echo "<p class='text-muted font-13 m-b-30'>";
                            echo "<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
                                 echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>No.</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Nama Item</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Jumlah</th>";
                                    echo"</tr>";
                                    echo "</thead>";
                                    echo "<tbody>";
                                    $no = 0; 
                                    $no++;
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td> $no </td>";
                                            echo "<td> $ia_key </td>";
                                            echo "<td> $ia_value </td>";
                                            $z++;
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    echo "</tbody>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</table>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo"</div>";
            }
        }
    }
```

[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNZbs.png) <== Click to view image.

Comment: Man, look this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: You need to repeat the structure of line <tr> and no the full table elem.

Comment: Tables are much better when made out of a hard material such as hardwood or metal, for example.

Comment: thanks guys, Solved now.. :)

Comment: have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your table structure outside of the `foreach()` loop:

```
$no = 0; 
echo "<div class='row'>";
echo "<div class='col-sm-12'>";
echo "<h4 class='m-t-0 header-title'></h4>";
echo "<div class='table-responsive m-b-20'>";
echo "<p class='text-muted font-13 m-b-30'>";
echo "<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>No.</th>";
echo "<th>Nama Item</th>";
echo "<th>Jumlah</th>";
echo"</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

foreach ($item_array as $ia_key => $ia_value) 
{
    //$theitems = explode('|',$ia_key);
    for($x = 0; $x < count($ia_key); $x++) 
    {
        if (($ia_value>=$support))
        {

            $no++;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> $no </td>";
            echo "<td> $ia_key </td>";
            echo "<td> $ia_value </td>";
            $z++;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is that you echo the table in the loop and this result in define table another table each time within the loop re arrange your code to print the table before the loop and end it after the loop may be like this

```
 echo "<div class='row'>";
                                echo "<div class='col-sm-12'>";
                                    echo "<h4 class='m-t-0 header-title'></h4>";
                                    echo "<div class='table-responsive m-b-20'>";
                                        echo "<p class='text-muted font-13 m-b-30'>";
                                        echo "<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
  echo "<thead>";
                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                    echo "<th>No.</th>";
                                                    echo "<th>Nama Item</th>";
                                                    echo "<th>Jumlah</th>";
                                                echo"</tr>";
                                                echo "</thead>";

            for($x = 0; $x < count($ia_key); $x++) 
                    {
                        if (($ia_value>=$support))
                        {

                                                echo "<tbody>";
                                                $no = 0; 
                                                $no++;
                                                    echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td> $no </td>";
                                                        echo "<td> $ia_key </td>";
                                                        echo "<td> $ia_value </td>";
                                                        $z++;
                                                    echo "</tr>";
                                                echo "</tbody>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                                                                }
                }
    echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go revisit PHP basics. It is a template language, instead of
echoing out multiple  strings you can just close the  PHP tag (`?>`) and
write your desired  output there directly. Then reopen when  you need to
go back to PHP code (`<?php`).

As for your exact problem, that's because you echo the beginning and end
of each table  inside your loop, so it happens  multiple times. Instead,
you want to  start your table and  end it outside the loop,  and use the
loop to loop over what's repeated: *lines*.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12'>
    <h4 class='m-t-0 header-title'></h4>
    <div class='table-responsive m-b-20'>
      <p class='text-muted font-13 m-b-30'>
      <table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Nama Item</th>
            <th>Jumlah</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($item_array as $ia_key => $ia_value) 
    {
        for($x = 0; $x < count($ia_key); $x++) 
        {
            if (($ia_value>=$support))
            {
                $no = 0; 
                $no++;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> $no </td>";
                echo "<td> $ia_key </td>";
                echo "<td> $ia_value </td>";
                $z++;
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, revise your logic. You're resetting `$no` every iteration, to then
increment it.

Comment: Ideally, as you will see with time and with larger project, try to keep presentation separated from logic. Instead of embedding code in HTML you may want to just call a template or simply require another file. The cleaner your code is, the better to develop, spot bugs, and maintain.